# PHP array converter to variable is it possible?

Tags: php

i have :

```
      function asdf(){
      $a1 = [1,2,3]; 
      $a2 = [3,4,5];
            $a = array(
                  "x" => $a1,
                  "y" => $a2
            );
        return $a;
      }
```

is it possible to do this with foreach ? :

```
$a = $this->asdf();
$x = $a['x']; $y = $a['y];
```

Comment: **"i have :"** what you have doesn't exist as valid php code.

Comment: @PedroLobito, thanks.. i edited it.. it's array i mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is considered bad practice all things considered, as it makes your code unreadable.

```
function asdf(){
    $a1 = [1,2,3]; 
    $a2 = [3,4,5];
    $a = array(
          "x" => $a1,
          "y" => $a2
    );
    return $a;
}

$a = asdf();
foreach($a as $index => $value){
    $$index = $value;
}
var_dump($x);
var_dump($y);
```

Outputs:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(3)
  [1]=>
  int(4)
  [2]=>
  int(5)
}
```

Example: http://ideone.com/yQvn78

Comment: Yes, but it will be faster to use `[]` notation. e.g. `$a[] = 'value';` as opposed to `array_push`